# sqlite greater than comparison(>) doesn't seem to work for custom types

Tags: sqlite, string-comparison

Does SQLite support greater than(>) comparison between two custom objects? For example, if I run this query:

```
select myDate from test where myDate > '2010'
```

against my SQLite database, which contains several records either earlier or later than year 2010, I expect to get a return that only contains those whose date is later than year 2010. By the way, I store dates as a registered custom type in myDate Column.
However, in reality, it returned every records, basically ignored my WHERE clause completely.
Is such comparison supported at all?
Many thanks.

Comment: What is the content of your column and wich what data type?

Comment: @Mr.d: custom type, which is a python object registered with sqlite.register_adapter and converter. Basically the content is just datetime with timezone infos.

Comment: I meant what is the physical DB data type of the column?

Comment: Sure. content is just time info with some timezone info, e.g: 2013-09-08 21:33 PDT, etc.

Comment: phisically they should be just strings, as python's official sqlite3 API documentation says, all adapters should automatically convert your objects into strings before storing into the designated column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select myDate from test 
where substr(myDate, 1, 4) > '2010'
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d41d8/746)

Comment: I tried this method, it gave me an error:sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: year. Sorry to point it out, I do appreciate your quick answer. Could it be python's own quirck?

Comment: Is there a way to invoke methods on those objects stored in the selected column? That way I can add a "year" function to my python class.

Comment: Oh my goodness! It works! What's the magic method substr here? Could you give a little bit explanation?:)

Comment: It extract the first 4 letters from your date string. Only the year part.

Comment: Can I invoke methods on those objects stored in the selected column in WHERE clause? That way I can add a more flexible comparison method to my python class.

Comment: You can use SQLite function in your select statement. Just look up which ones you need.

Comment: No I mean the custom objects' own methods,  can I invoke?

Comment: So that I can query like: select myDate from test 
where myDate.daydream() > '2010'

Comment: No that is not possible.

Comment: Many thanks, very helpful, I wish I could give you more points but my stratus does not allow me.